# Recursively trying to solve the queen challenge, but getting a weird output

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, printing, n-queens

Right now I am trying to solve the problem where there are eight queens on a 8x8 board, and you have to place them where none of them can capture the other. This is pretty popular problem to use recursion on, however I still can't figure out exactly why it is not working. Here is the main code for checking if a placement is valid, and then if it is a valid placement the queen will be placed, otherwise try to place the queen at a position one unit to the right (a new column, same row). Here is the code:

```
private boolean placeQueen(int row, int column)
{
    if(check(row, column))
    {
        board[column][row] = 'Q';
        queenCount++;
        return true;
    }else if(column == board.length)
    {
        queenCount++;
        return false;
    }else
    {
        return (placeQueen(row, column + 1));
    }
    //return false;
}

private boolean check(int row, int column)
{
    //checking vertical axis
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        if(board[column][i] == 'Q' && i != row)
        { //does not check its own row
            return false;
        }
    }

    int i = column;
    int j = row;
    //left one, up one
    while(i >= 0 && j >= 0)
    {
        try{
            if(board[i--][j--] == 'Q')
            {
                return false;
            }else
            {
                i--;
                j--;
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    i = column;
    j = row;
    //right one, up one
    while(i <= 8 && j >= 0)
    {
        try{
            if(board[i++][j--] == 'Q')
            {
                return false;
            }else
            {
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have to only check for the upward diagonals, since I am placing the queens as it goes down. Here is the output, which is not correct:

```
Q * * * * * * * 
* Q * * * * * * 
* * * Q * * * * 
* * Q * * * * * 
* * * * * * * Q 
* * * * * * Q * 
* * * * Q * * * 
* * * * * Q * *
```

Is it something with how I am doing it recursively, or just how I am checking the diagonals?

Here is how I am running it

```
        public void run()
        {
             createBoard();
             while(queenCount != board.length)
             {
                 placeQueen(queenCount, 0);
             }
             printBoard();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of many examples on
[*Queens problem*](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Queens.java.html)

Hope it'll help...